# Stack around the variable A (array) or n (size of the array) was corrupted

Tags: visual-c++

This program checks distinctness in an array. (no repeated values in an array I.e if 1 2 3 3 4 is an array it is not distinct). this code Won't compile although (I believe that) index of array did not go out of range in for loop. 
theRun-Time Check Failure says stack around variable 'n' was corrupted when I enter n =12. BUT says stack around variable 'A' was corrupted when I enter n = 10. with exactly the same variables entered in the array in the second step. (the error shows up after entering the fourth integer)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    int A[] = {0};
    int integer;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the array\n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter "<<n<<" integers\n";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        cin>>A[i];  
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < n - i; j++)
        {
            if(A[j+1] > A[j])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = A[j];
                A[j+1] = A[j];
                A[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] - A[i+1] ==0 ){
            cout<<"\nThe Array Is Not Distinct !\n";
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<"\nThe Array Is Distinct !\n";
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The program has undefined behavior. `A` is an array of size 1 and you can not take input to it for more than 1 element. Use std::vector.